# OkHttp and Retrofit crashing with SendBird v3

Tags: android, gradle, okhttp, sendbird

So I'm running into an issue integrating SendBird into an existing Android application. The existing application uses React Native for it's front end and I'm implementing SendBird into the native Android side. I've followed the tutorial and have an example app running just fine. However at run time, I'm running into issues with OkHttp

The issue arises AFTER I call the init for SenBird's UIKit

SendbirdUIKit.init(new SendbirdUIKitAdapter())

Once I call this code the issue happens. If I attempt to call an API using Retrofit I get the following crash

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.***, PID: 17631
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter$Companion$factory$1.matchesSocket(ConscryptSocketAdapter.kt:58)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.DeferredSocketAdapter.matchesSocket(DeferredSocketAdapter.kt:37)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Android10Platform.kt:51)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:375)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.***.APIHandler.lambda$get7BossClient$0(APIHandler.java:51)
    at com.***.APIHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.intercept(Unknown Source:2)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version.major()' on a null object reference
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(ConscryptPlatform.kt:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.<clinit>(ConscryptPlatform.kt:115)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter$Companion$factory$1.matchesSocket(ConscryptSocketAdapter.kt:58) 
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.DeferredSocketAdapter.matchesSocket(DeferredSocketAdapter.kt:37) 
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Android10Platform.kt:51) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:375) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at com.***.APIHandler.lambda$get7BossClient$0(APIHandler.java:51) 
    at com.***.APIHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.intercept(Unknown Source:2) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

And if I try to launch an Activity of SendBird's like the ChannelListActivity I get the following error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.seveneleven.rnd.tabasco.ris2, PID: 16711
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter$Companion$factory$1.matchesSocket(ConscryptSocketAdapter.kt:58)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.android.DeferredSocketAdapter.matchesSocket(DeferredSocketAdapter.kt:37)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Android10Platform.kt:51)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:375)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version.major()' on a null object reference
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(ConscryptPlatform.kt:129)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.<clinit>(ConscryptPlatform.kt:115)
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter$Companion$factory$1.matchesSocket(ConscryptSocketAdapter.kt:58) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.android.DeferredSocketAdapter.matchesSocket(DeferredSocketAdapter.kt:37) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Android10Platform.kt:51) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:375) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) 
    at com.sendbird.android.shadow.okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

It looks like SendBird's UIKit has it's own OkHttp3 implementation that is overriding the library I have locally. Below is what I have listed in my gradle

````
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.11.0'
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'logging-interceptor', version: '4.10.0'
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.2")

implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.11.0'
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'logging-interceptor', version: '4.10.0'
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.2")```
````

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: What about it? The NullPointerException is coming from the same file as the ExceptionInInitializerError (ConscryptPlatform) which is in the OkHttp library